# Combining MD5 Analysis with Filename in single Output

Tags: powershell, filehash

I am struggling to combine the output from two commands into a single CSV / TXT file.

The first command is to recursively search a folder and create an MD5 number for each document. This is then exported to a CSV file that includes the full path.

`dir -recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Export-CSV MD5ofFolder.csv`

The second command is to retrieve all the filenames within the folder (and sub-folders) WITHOUT including any pathing:

```
get-childitem -recurse|foreach {$_.name} > filename.txt
```

In a perfect world, I would be able to export a single CSV or TXT document that contains the MD5 values, the full path, and the filename (with extension).

I note that my second code string also produces the folder names in the output, which is not desirable. I am able to produce a text output without the folder names, but the code is ugly, and it doesn't do what I want:

```
dir -recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | dir -recurse | foreach {$_.name} > filename.txt
```

I am sure this is a simple problem for someone smarter than me, so any and all help would be appreciated - I am VERY new to PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the name to the output from `Get-FileHash` with `Select-Object` and a calculated property:

```
dir -recurse |Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 |Select-Object Hash,Path,@{Name='Name';Expression={[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.Path)}} |Export-Csv filename.csv
```

Now you have it all in a single csv

Comment: Wow. Thanks for your help! That string works EXACTLY as I was hoping. I should have come to this forum way sooner! I really appreciate the assistance.